# ZF2: Google block smtp email

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, smtp, gmail

Until now I have using this code to send e-mails from my web application without any problem, through smtp server from gmail.

```
$smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();

$smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setConnectionClass('login')
    ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
    ->setConnectionConfig(array(
        'username' => 'something@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'some_password',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
    ));

$transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
$transport->send($message);
```

But, today I can't send any e-mail from my web application and I have received an e-mail where google said to me that has been blocked an access not identificated.

What happend? How can I send right now e-mails using the smtp server from gmail without problems?

Comment: try adding in TLS port, ('port' => 587)

Comment: I added port 587 but the result was the same, so I remove port :(

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Really, I don't receive any error, when I try to send the email the process doesn't finish. And I receive an email from google where they tell me that someone has try to access to muy email. This "someone" is my web application :). I have been able to send emails without problems with the code I have posted but right now I can not send emails :(